# textNoSuggestions is ignored by 2.0.1 emulator

Tags: android

textNoSuggestions is ignored by 2.0.1 emulator...am I doing something wrong?  I am using the stock settings which has a 12 key softkeyboard.

Comment: Can you post your layout XML or the code that you are using the configure the TextView.

Comment: <EditText android:id="@+id/answer_edit_box" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false" android:selectAllOnFocus="false" android:imeOptions="flagNoAccessoryAction|flagNoEnterAction" android:layout_below="@+id/definition" android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"></EditText>

Comment: I have included textVisiblePassword because I want this to work on 1.6. textVisiblePassword worked fine for this purpose in 1.6

Answer (score 1):

Try Kurru's and also jax's answer

`android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"`

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789905/how-to-turnoff-suggestions-in-edittext)