# How can I turn off suggestions in EditText?

Tags: android

How can I turn off suggestions in EditText in Android?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's already described in the link Yoni Samlan posted. You should read the documentation correctly ;)

There is a method called setInputType. All you need is to call it with

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

Comment: Not supported on the HTC Desire

Comment: Strange thing, on my Desire and Wildfire when setting android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" in xml it does not work. Setting it in the code work like a charm mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS); No problem with my Droid with the two methods.

Comment: @ol_v_er: neither solution works for me, in a Galaxy Note with Hacker's keyboard.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit input type flag is a flag to the keyboard, it's up to the implementation of the keyboard to do the right thing with it.

Comment: Important thing is to NOT `or` it with `TYPE_CLASS_TEXT` otherwise it kept overriding the 'no suggestions' flag.

Answer (score 117):

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

according to [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.devel/143278), may or may not be supported by the IME (the keyboard).

**However**, this seems to work more often

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```

Comment: `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"` did the trick for my Wildfire and Desire HD. Tx!

Comment: @Kurru: This works, but I get an ugly NullPointerException crash when trying 'event.getKeyCode()'.

Comment: Please note, this will cause an issue with Swype keyboards. The space will not automatically add it self after a word has been "swyped". Also, the voice to text feature will not work as the feature is disabled since the Swype keyboard see this as a "password field".

Comment: It seems that `textVisiblePassword` also causes problems with Japanese keyboards. Any idea on that one?

Comment: This also breaks the characters cap functionality

Comment: And it breaks the stylus input on tablets too because it "explicilty tells software keyboard, that content of this field should not be added to any vocabulary, synchronized through network, added to usage statistics or anything like this" [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61592084/1014048)

Comment: This is a bad idea - you are misusing the API which will lead to unexpected problems. In particular, setting `textVisiblePassword` might trigger autofill which you don't want in this case.

If the keyboard does not respond to the `textNoSuggestions` flag, that's a bug with that keyboard, and that should be fixed.

Answer (score 17):

This seems to work better;

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

i.e. the visible password and no suggestion input types are OR'd together

To make sure you can also add this attribute to your edit text

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```

Answer (score 6):

`android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`. See the [xml attribute documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType) and this Android developers [blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/updating-applications-for-on-screen.html).

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. But i an dynamically reating the edittext i want to do the same in java code.Please help me.

Comment: Tseng above has it right -- most Android xml-settable attributes have matching set[attributeName] methods, in this case setInputType.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS` in activity, it will work fine. In case of DialogFragment, you should place `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS` at `onActivityCreated()` handler as below:-

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    EditText editTextUsername =  (EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
    editTextUsername.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the next workaround - I noticed that when sending Email messages no suggestion appear-

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions|textEmailAddress"
```

It is not 100% but it is working :)

Comment: Working perfect!

Answer (score 1):

If Editext/TextInputEditText has more than 1 line
then add textMultiLine

```
 android:minLines="10"
 android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textMultiLine|textVisiblePassword"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
android:importantForAutofill="no"
```

Comment: This flag is related to the Autofill framework (for usernames and passwords), not to text suggestions.

Comment: You're right @Remc4. You can use `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` for  text suggestions.

Comment: Surprisingly that makes no difference. That's why everyone also adds textVisiblePassword flag.