# Android how to get Suggested strings array of the TextEdit

Tags: android

Is there a way to get an array of the suggestions strings which are shown when you typing in `EditText`? The problem is I have an `EditText` and in case of user use "Show Suggestions" option the result of the string from this `EditText` is different in case of user pressed, lets say UI button (this is a Button from the layout), and a return button at the soft keyboard. In first case user gets an exact string but in second - it gets corrected (suggested) string even user do NOT select this suggestion. How to solve this problem? How to get from EditText "suggested" string? Do I need to implement my own IME?

Comment: Here is an example:
http://gyazo.com/74c1c69096c87dbc1533bf298b62904f
If user tap on "Send" button - it will send "Tert"
but is user tap "<-" (return) button on the soft keyboard - it will send "Tertiary" word, as Android suggests.
What I need is to have same behavior by clicking "Send" UI button and by clicking Return soft keyboard button.
Thus I need to know, if there is a way to get corrected (suggested) string from the EditText view in case of do NOT select suggested word and tap "Send" UI button.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you ?  [Hello Auto Complete](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html) 
Or if you want to write one on your own.. [Writing your own autocompleteview](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/08/writing-your-own-autocompletetextview/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to disable suggestions or to modify them?
If you want to disable them completely, check this out:
[How to disable displaying "suggestions" on the Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281838/how-to-disable-displaying-suggestions-on-the-soft-keyboard)