# how to avoid soft keyboard showing auto correct suggestion?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I dont want my softkeyboard show these suggestions and any of the symbols like !, ", ,, :,'.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To stop offering suggestions, add the following attribute to your EditText in XML:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

and/or add multiple types using `|` as below:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions | text"
```

Comment: No, it will only skip suggestions... and I don't think by default alphabet-only keyboard is possible, unless you design one for yourself. But as an alternate, you may use `TextWatcher` on your EditText to omit unwanted characters

Answer (score 2):

You can add this line to you EditText

> android:inputType="textFilter"

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488987/444324) why it sometimes better than textNoSuggestions