# Disable keyboard autocorrect

Tags: android

I noticed with some apps/and even accessing websites on the phone, that my phone keyboard does not provide me with the auto correction feature.

I was wondering , is it possible to disable the auto correction in my app when someone clicks on EditText?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions"
```

in you xml.

Please see [how to avoid soft keyboard showing auto correct suggestion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519030/how-to-avoid-soft-keyboard-showing-auto-correct-suggestion)

**Update**

After reading [How to disable displaying "suggestions" on the Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281838/how-to-disable-displaying-suggestions-on-the-soft-keyboard) it seems the above will not work in a few rare cases.

Therefore, a safer way to go would be to use

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```

or

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```