# Tablet showing previously entered values from input field, even after having set autocomplete and autocorrect to 'off'

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, autocomplete

I have an HTML page which has an input field with `type="text"`, `autocomplete="off"` and `autocorrect="off"`

Although this turns off the drop down that appears below the input field with previously entered values, I still get these values in the suggestions that appear above my soft keyboard in *Samsung Galaxy Tab S* tablet. Please see the image below.

[image]

Setting `autocomplete="off"` and `autocorrect="off"` works fine for Sony Xperia Z tablet. But *Samsung Galaxy Tab S* is giving issue, which has android 4.4.2 and chrome browser version 38.0.2125.102.

Anyone knows why?

Note: I know i can turn off suggestions from keyboard settings or change the keyboard itself, but i want it to work without the user having to do that. For example sony xperia z tablet have suggestions turned on but it never shows suggestions for input fields that have autocomplete=off, and shows suggestions otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be way off base here, but my thought is that its the keyboard you are running.  Samsung's default keyboard on the Tab might have autocomplete/autocorrect by default.  There should be another keyboard you can switch to (whether it be android's default or something else). Switching might get you the result you are looking for.

Comment: I know i can turn off suggestions from keyboard settings or change the keyboard itself, but i want it to work without the user having to do that. For example sony xperia z tablet have suggestions turned on but it never shows suggestions for input fields that have autocompleted=off

Comment: If it works on the Xperia Z and not the Tab, then that should be proof enough that it is the Tab.  That's the problem with Android - everyone has their own version of everything, and some things fall through the cracks.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Quote yanchenko from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4488987/2026478

> When developing for 2.0+, the supposed way is setting android:inputType="textNoSuggestions" (ref). Unfortunately, suggestions are still shown on HTC Desire 2.2 (and probably other HTC Sense devices as well).
>    With "android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" the sotware keyboard by HTC won't allow you to switch language.
>    So I stick to "android:inputType="textFilter" to disable suggestions.

Or programmatically
Quote 1ka from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5039551/2026478

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SearchText);
et.setInputType(et.getInputType()
| EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS
| EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER);
```

Source: [How to disable displaying "suggestions" on the Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281838/how-to-disable-displaying-suggestions-on-the-soft-keyboard)

Comment: Sorry may be my question was not that clear. But you got it wrong. I am using HTML to build my page and accessing it through browser. Its not an app. Thanks for your time btw