# Why does backspace stop working if I set TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS on my AutocompleteTextView?

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
AutoCompleteTextView et = new AutoCompleteTextView(context);
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

With this code the `AutoCompleteTextView` prevents the backspace key from working! If I change the class type to EditText, the same behaviour occurs.

But with this code the backspace key works:

```
AutoCompleteTextView et = new AutoCompleteTextView(context);
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
```

I don't want auto-suggestions from the keyboard, that's why I'm using an AutocompleteTextView! Any suggestions?

I'm testing against Android 2.3.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have found you need to use this instead:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
```

For more info: [How can I turnoff suggestions in EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789905/how-can-i-turnoff-suggestions-in-edittext)