# Android EditText Max Length

Tags: android, android-edittext

I set up a max length of text in an EditText field.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/courseDescriptionField"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5"
            android:maxLength="@integer/max_course_description_limit"
            android:gravity="left|top" >
        </EditText>
```

The problem for me however is, that, text STOPS appearing after 140 characters, but it still continues to type, except that text just doesn't appear, but however, it does appear in the "buffer" (meaning the suggestion thing) if that's what you would call it.

As a side note, I am using a TextWatcher to keep track of the limit. Is there any way to completely limit the amount of text, so that when there are 140 characters, nothing happens when something other than backspace/delete is pressed?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to limit text length of EditText in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285412/limit-text-length-of-edittext-in-android)

Use `android:maxLength="140"`

That should work. :)

Comment: I have same problem but this is not work for me

Comment: What's happening in yours? ask a new question and put up your code in it and I will have a look. put a link to your question here so I can find it

Comment: Same problem ! Is there a solution ?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. Can anyone explain why this would work versus using an app constant? Seems like having the char limit as a value in xml shouldn't change how the text buffer works.

Answer (score 45):

I had the same problem.

Here is a workaround

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
android:maxLength="6"
```

Thx to [How can I turnoff suggestions in EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789905/how-can-i-turnoff-suggestions-in-edittext)

Comment: That is funny that modifying the inputType allows maxLength to work properly, preventing users from typing more buffer. I wish Google fix this.

Comment: It looks like only textNoSuggestions is needed to delete letters when pressing backkey.

Comment: This is strange, wonder if google knows of this bug!

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, limiting the maxLength only doesn't do it

Comment: You have no control over the software keyboard. The effect of various features and flags on the software keyboard is implementation-dependent. You only control the EditText itself.

Comment: This is the correct answer! The buffer doesn't keep filling after the "maxLength" limit has been reached!

Comment: Hi, I'm the guy that posted the "Accepted" answer. I agree with @Nactus. This should be the accepted answer. My answer doesn't solve the problem completely.

Comment: nice answer... working good.

Comment: @SeungUnHam Actually for me it's the other way around. I only needed `textVisiblePassword` to make it work. However, `textCapWords` has no effect now on some phones..

Comment: This is the workaround to use when you don't need suggestions. However, if you need both the length limitation and suggestions this doesn't work. This issue exists since pretty much the inception of Android and Google doesn't care about fixing it. Sad..

Comment: @DennisK, I suppose my ugly solution can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58372842/2914140.

Answer (score 18):

```
EditText editText= ....;
InputFilter[] fa= new InputFilter[1];
fa[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(8);
editText.setFilters(fa);
```

Comment: Single line: `editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxlength) });`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. It works perfectly fine when you add this:

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

to your `EditText`.

Answer (score 6):

**You may try this**

```
 EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myeditText);
    et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilter.LengthFilter(140) }); // maximum length is 140
```

Answer (score 2):

If you used `maxLength = 6` , some times what you are entering those characters are added in top of the keyboard called suggestions. So when you deleting entered letters that time it will delete suggestions first and then actual text inside `EditText`. For that you need to remove the suggestions.just add

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`
```

or

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

It will remove those suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see a counter label you can use `app:counterEnabled` and `android:maxLength`, like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  app:counterEnabled="true">

  <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="420" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**DO NOT** set `app:counterMaxLength` on `TextInputLayout` because it will conflict with `android:maxLength` resulting into the issue of invisible chars after the text hits the size limit.

Answer (score 0):

For me this solution works:

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```