# How to stop taking input after EditText length crosses a limit

Tags: android, android-edittext

I know there are a couple of questions already been asked, but I have a little different query.

How do we put a limit on the maximum number of characters to be inputted in `EditText`? Whether I do this

```
android:maxLength="7"
```

or this

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.zip)).setFilters(new InputFilter[] {
    new InputFilter.LengthFilter(7)
});
```

I can still type into the text field, though it's not visible and not taken into account. If I keep typing, the input becomes invisible after the limit, but the `test-suggestions` keep building for higher number of letters.

Suppose my limit is 7 and I typed 10 letters, then I would only see the first 7 letters, but text-suggestions will show 10 letter words. Furthermore, I need to press backspace 3 times to actually start deleting letters from my shown 7-letter word.

So, my question is: Is there a way to stop taking input after a certain character length?

**PS**: Needless to say, but though I don't want input to be inputted after 7 letters, I would allow delete or backspace.

Comment: **Suppose my limit is 7 and I typed 10 letters, then I would only see the first 7 letters, but text-suggestions will show 10 letter words. Furthermore, I need to press backspace 3 times to actually start deleting letters from my shown 7-letter word** - True. I tried the same and found the exact case

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add this to your EditText. It will definitely work.

```
 android:inputType="textFilter"
```

I tried the same and it worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

try this,

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textVisiblePassword"
android:maxLength="7"
```

OR

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```

OR

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my concern is not about suggestions. It's mainly about stopping the input.

Comment: yup thats a bug so once you modified the input type maxLength would work perfectly, preventing users from typing more buffer.

Comment: look out for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083183/android-edittext-max-length/19222238#19222238

Answer (score 3):

This finally works for me:

```
edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Answer (score -1):

As @Madhur sugested, in your EditText xml add next line:

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:maxLength)

```
android:maxLength="7"
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's already what I'm doing rightnow. I need help with stopping the input as I've mentioned in my question.

Comment: Input should be stoped after that line, you can input onlu from 0-6 chars in your edit text.

Comment: **Suppose my limit is 7 and I typed 10 letters, then I would only see the first 7 letters, but text-suggestions will show 10 letter words. Furthermore, I need to press backspace 3 times to actually start deleting letters from my shown 7-letter word**. See what the OP is saying