# Edittext takes characters even after maxLength is reached

Tags: android, android-edittext

As the title implies Edittext takes character beyond maxLength. Its just that they are invisible. So you keep typing and it remains unnoticed. But when you backspace , you must backspace for the character count you entered after reaching maxLength value. Is this normal behaviour? If so, what is the workaround for it?

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_enter_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:hint="This is a hint."
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="4"        
        android:maxLength="200"
         />
```

Above is the code in xml.

EDIT: Okay, I found a workaround based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19222238/276949) answer.

Replaced : `android:inputType="textMultiLine"`

With : `android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"`

Unfortunately this turns off suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

if you use "setFilters" in your code, then your XML value will ignored. try this:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myeditText);
et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilter.LengthFilter(140) }); // maximum length is 140
```