# Turn off / disable suggestions for default keyboard on Samsung S5

Tags: android, keyboard, autosuggest

How do I turn off or disable suggestions on default keyboard for S5

I tried all the solutions (like "textNoSuggestion" from xml and code, all possible combination) given on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281838/how-to-disable-displaying-suggestions-on-the-soft-keyboard), but non of them is working for S5 default keyboard.

Am I missing something here??

Comment: There is no requirement for any input method editor to honor hints like `textNoSuggestion`. They are hints, not commands; it is up to the implementer of the input method editor to decide which hints they will honor and which they will not.

Comment: @CommonsWare so there is no solution to this ???

Comment: My point is even if you can find something that happens to have this effect on this input method editor, there may be others that still provide suggestions. I have no idea if there is a way to teach the S5 default input method editor to stop providing suggestions.

Comment: Have you also tried `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"`? I know this is the only way to make it work on a GalaxyTab 3.

Comment: @MarkusPenguin "textVisiblePassword" works from same [link][1] thanks


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5188119/2245895

Answer (score 2):

This works for Samsung A5:

```
editText.setInput(editText.getInputType()|InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
```

Comment: or you can set the XML attribute `textVisiblePassword` on the `inputType` in the `EditText`